# Unity - how to DeParent a gameobject on a XR Origin?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a Xr origin in the scene and the user can put on a helmet and take it off ( there is a trigger on the xr origin), the parenting works great however the deparenting doesn't? i have tried everything from

other.transform.SetParent(null, true);

other.transform.SetParent(null);

other.transform.parent = null;

[image: my hierarchy]

```
public static bool helmetIsOn;
private Transform parentTransform;
private XRGrabInteractable interactable;

private void Start()
{
    parentTransform = transform;
    helmetIsOn = false;
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("SafetyHelmet"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Helmet is On");
        interactable = other.gameObject.GetComponent<XRGrabInteractable>();

        if (interactable != null)
        {
            interactable.enabled = false;
        }

        other.transform.SetParent(parentTransform);
        other.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        other.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        StartCoroutine(EnableInteraction());
        helmetIsOn = true;
    }
}

private IEnumerator EnableInteraction()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    if (interactable != null)
    {
        interactable.enabled = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("SafetyHelmet"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Helmet is Off");
        other.transform.parent = null;
        helmetIsOn = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Debug.Log being called? If not then I'd check on your collisions.
If it is being called then maybe after the helmet is unparented it then enters the trigger again and is reparented?

Comment: Thats the thing the logs are correct, when i put on the helmet on i get "Helmet is On" and when it leaves the trigger i get "Helmet is Off" but its not deparenting? i made a IEnumerator deparentHelmet and called this function when the helmet was on and it was working correct.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i found a "solution", all i did was put it in a coroutine and call it after 0.5f seconds and its working.

```
private IEnumerator DeParent()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    helmet.transform.parent = null;
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("SafetyHelmet"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Helmet is Off");
        StartCoroutine(DeParent()); 
        helmetIsOn = false;
    }
}
```